# Packages issues with error messages saying fatal issue

Tags: r

I have a set of packages that I load when I start working in any R session . Never had a problem and today getting the following two messages and can not really figure out where is the problem. Any help? See the images

[image]

Then the whole R session gets a message as well. See image
[image] R error message

Any one know how to sort that out?

Comment: can you update your package xfun to a version 0.39 or higher?

Comment: Do you have an .Rprofile file that automatically loads packages at start up? By default nothing should be loaded but you have some code somewhere that's trying to load old pacakges.

Comment: Thank you, Mike. I have updated the packages and this sorted out the problem. Very much appreciated

Comment: MrFlick, thank you. No, I did not have an Rprofile that automatically loads packages at start up. I updated the xfun package and problem solved. Thank you

Comment: If the failure to update of `xfun` causes RStudio to dump/crash the R session, then I suggest this could be a [bug report](https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/new/choose) on the IDE. To be honest, I didn't read through all of the issues that include `xfun` (there are many, most are likely completely unrelated to this), but at least starting the issue might help others find it and see your workaround. And from there, perhaps Posit devs will be able to find the underlying assumptions that caused the core-dump.

Comment: Thank you r2evans, alway trying to help. Very much appreciated